How to see certain colums and rows on an embedded google sheet on google sites
I have a google sheet with multiple tabs that I want users to be able to interact with. It is a booking system for a laptop trolley that has 30 laptops so users can book a certain amount of laptops for a time and date, and all users can see how many have already been booked and how many are left to book. Each tab is a new week. I have locked some cells so that users can't edit things like dates and certain headings but the rest I want users to be able to input data. The issue I'm having is I wanted to share it by publishing in a google site, but I just cannot get it to show the specific columns and rows I want. I want them to be able to see A1:M27 without having to scroll. Is this posssible?
The code I have for this is:
<center><iframe width="100%" height="80%" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XAN5mabI6AiDeuZiqJcQOl46hZr89As2gL-QMJ7OMsQ/edit?usp=sharing?&amp;rm=minimal&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe></center>

where the width and height I have tried multiple different px values,  as well as trying percentages but I just can't get it to show exactly what I want.
Here is a link to the site: https://sites.google.com/ktcs.ie/laptop-booking/home

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Could you share the URL of your Google site?

Sorry, just added it there now.
